# I can't connect POSTGRES database using SQL Shell (command line tool)

Tags: windows, postgresql, psql

I've got a problem during connecting database from command line tool - SQL Shell. I cant connect database using command `\c test localhost postgres 5432`

After using it I receive message:

> could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Unknown host
> Previous connection kept

Although I can connect using pgAdmin 4.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
I'm working on Windows 10, I have the newest version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: Look up the order of the arguments for `\c`

Answer (score 1):

According to postgres document if you want CLI for to connect database you have to use like that:

```
=> \c mydb myuser host.dom 6432
=> \c service=foo
=> \c "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb connect_timeout=10 sslmode=disable"
=> \c -reuse-previous=on sslmode=require    -- changes only sslmode
=> \c postgresql://tom@localhost/mydb?application_name=myapp
```